# Mass assignment with update_attributes does not update collection_singular_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mass-assignment

I have a simple `User` model which is associated to many `Town` objects using a join table (`has_and_belongs_to_many`). Now I'd like to update the towns belonging to a particular user by assigning a list of comma-separated town ids (coming directly from the form sent as a HTTP POST parameter).

The user object is saved using the following controller code:

```
@current_object.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

The `params[:user]` includes `town_ids` which is, for example, set to `1,4,6`.

Unfortunately, this does not update the user-town associations at all. However, if I do it manually, it works beautifully well:

```
User.find(:first).town_ids = "1,4,6" # this saves automatically
```

Could it just be that it is not possible to mass-assign these `collection_singular_ids` fields?

My user model contains the following:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :towns

# necessary for mass-assignment, otherwise it results in an exception:
attr_accessible :town_ids
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `town_ids` as an *array*:

```
User.find(:first).update_attributes(:town_ids=>[1,4,6])
```

If you pass the ids as a string Rails will attempt to convert the string to an integer:

```
"1,4,6".to_i # => 1
```